# Doing 301 redirects of urls containing a specific string caused by hacking

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a wordpress site that was hacked and hundreds of urls were created that no longer exist after I cleaned the site up. I have noticed a lot of these urls contains a specific keyword as displayed below
http://www.capecrossfit.com/kamagra-holland/ - I need to rewrite all urls containing the word **kamagra** to http://www.capecrossfit.com/ - I have tried all the recommendations on near similar requests on this site with no joy, can anyone please advise how this can be done with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Pace this rule as very first rule (just below `RewriteEngine On` line):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /kamagra-holland|buy-kamagra-europe|kamagra-super-jelly [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Will this apply to all the other links I am referring to eg buy-kamagra-europe/
kamagra-super-jelly/

Comment: You can use regex alternation as you can see in my updated rule now.